# Unexpected behaviour on deploying MVC app

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net-mvc-2, windows-server-2008

today I have deployed my first MVC 2 application on Windows Server 2008, and something strange happen.
Authentication was requested on almost every pages, even to access 'scripts' and 'contents' folders.

This was strange because this behavior doesn't occur on my development environment.

Then I have setup IIS in my Win7, to test it on IIS environment, and every works as expected.

So my question is, does anyone have any idea what could be happening on Windows Server 2008 deployment?

Thanks

Comment: Today I have tried the copy tool, but still no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing many situations I have found out that, this problem was due to permissions on Application Pool, and not related to MVC